# Turtle: Difference between "rdf:type" and "a"

Tags: rdf, ontology, semantic-web, rdfs, turtle-rdf

I tried to figure out the difference between:

```
<#blabla> rdf:type owl:Class
```

and:

```
<#blabla> a owl:Class
```

Is `a` just a shortcut for `rdf:type`?

Comment: it's not OWL Turtle, Turtle is an RDF serialization format. And to answer your question: https://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/#iri-a

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is "a" just a shortcut for rdf:type?

Yes.

Comment: In the predicate position only :).